# Mocking an API call that should return a delayed response?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, aws-lambda, ruby-mocha

Using Mocha Minitest, I'm trying to mock an API call (e.g. dynamodb_client.scan() ) that should wait n seconds before returning a response.

The dynamodb scan is a subfunction inside my actual test subject, which is against an entire lambda:

```
  def test_lambda_handler_with_delayed_scan_response

    @dynamo_client = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
      region: 'mock-region',
      access_key_id: 'aws-user',
      secret_access_key: 'aws-key'
    )
    Aws::DynamoDB::Client.stubs(:new).returns(@dynamo_client)

    scan_params_1 = {some_key: "some_value"} 
    response = {code: 200}

    @dynamo_client.stubs(:scan).with(scan_params_1).returns(response)

    lambda_handler(event: event, context: @context)

    # addtl logic asserting the log output of lambda_handler() matches an expected output file

  end
```

What I've tried so far:

```
@dynamo_client.stubs(:scan).with(scan_params_1).returns(sleep 5; response)
```

Doesn't work because the sleep is executing during the test setup, instead of during invocation of the method inside lambda_handler

```
@dynamo_client.stubs(:scan).with(scan_params_1).returns(proc {sleep 5; response })
```

Doesn't work because the method invocation returns the proc itself, but the proc has to be executed with proc.call, which the lambda_handler would obviously not do.

Comment: There’s a long standing feature request but it hasn’t been implemented (yet): https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/224. Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742565/how-to-return-a-dynamic-value-from-a-mocha-mock-in-ruby

Comment: What do you want the stub to pause for 5 seconds? I would argue that one of the reasons to stub web requests in tests is to make the test much faster, because they do not have to wait for external dependencies.

Comment: @spickermann need a time delay factor to test a logic section within the lambda that deals with cutting off processing before lambda times out.

Comment: @xwan not sure if this is recommended approach or not but you can override a method implementation in an object by simply redefining it like `def @dynamo_client.scan; sleep 5; response; end` and that will override the method implementation for that specific object.

Comment: @AbdulRehman that's not "ideal" but at the same time this is definitely a great stopgap! I will try that for now.